# Encrypt disk/partition after install

Tags: 16.04, encryption, ext4

I've been tasked to secure the data on one of our Ubuntu 16.04 boxes. It runs a website and MySQL with pretty heavy traffic and queries.

A few million static files are on RAID-1 spinning disks and the website itself, database etc. is on SSD's. Everything is EXT4 without LVM.

Is there a way to encrypt a disk,partition or whole system after install? Something like Bitlocker for Windows.

Ideally I would want to prevent the access to files on disk if the disks ever get pulled from the server and installed into another machine. But it should also work as it is now without user intervention of the server ever gets rebooted due to power outages or whatever. There's also some stuf always running in a tmux session which starts via cron after boot.

Cheers.

Comment: The only way is to make an encrypted partition, move your data to the new partition,  and configure it. Automatic decryption on boot is possible, look up luks and keys, but it is a bit self defeating, what really is the point if it automatically decrypts at boot?

Comment: Well if they can't SSH in they can't access anything I figured. I was worried about pulling drives and placing them into a second system to look at the contents.

Comment: Yes encryption will help with that - pulling the drive, but if you configure the drive to automatically decrypt then they are back to pulling the drive again.

Comment: You can cnfigure LUKS to automatically decrypt using a key file, but the key file needs to be accessed during boot, where are you going to up it ? On the hard drive ? On a usb ? either way, if someone has physical access they have the drive and the key.